# parsing json with jrock in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, jayrock

I am attempting to parse some json I am getting back from a service.
For example it's returning

```
      {
  "error" : 
  {
    "code" : 500, 
    "message" : "Error Executing Task. Error executing tool.", 
    "details" : []
  }
}
```

All I need is the text in the message field.  Using jayrock what is the easity way to get to the data.  I have:

```
 Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim jarray As Jayrock.Json.JsonObject
request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim reader As JsonTextReader = New JsonTextReader((New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)))


        jarray = Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.Import(reader)
```

what is the most efficant way of getting the "message" data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for myself, but I'd write it this way:

```
Dim cMessage As String = "{ ""error"" : { ""code"" : 500, " & _
                                """message"" : ""Error Executing Task. " & _
                                "Error executing tool.""," & _
                                """details"" : [] " & _
                                "}" & _
                                "}"

Dim objResponse As JsonObject


objResponse = CType(JsonConvert.Import(cMessage), JsonObject)

MsgBox( "Last response was: " + objResponse("error")("message") )
```

P.S.: Don't forget to import Jayrock.Json and Jayrock.Json.Conversion